# What is the Best Way to Installing BOINC software?

Tags: virtualbox, software-center, boinc

10 Years After ...
Ubuntu 20.04.1   Boinc 7.16  VirtualBox 6.1

Tried using the Ubuntu Software path ... jacked-up my platform so badly I had to re-install [new install with nothing else added so no frost].

Tried again using the Ububntu Software to install ... installed just Boinc, no problem. Installed VirtualBox and got "No VM Found". Removed & re-installed, but had to use command-line for virtualbox as it disappeared from Ubuntu Software - same deal but didn't crash this time.

Third attempt completely command line [sudo apt-get install boinc-client boinc-manager] then installed VM [sudo apt-get install virtualbox].

Now I'm waiting for "Communicating with Client" ... going on 30 minutes now.

Perfectly willing to completely rebuild if needed, this will be a single-purpose device so it's an easy process.

All I need are a few street signs ...

Answer (score 0):

I installed VirtualBox first then Boinc. The Boinc installer calls(looks for) VB during the install.
It's been a few months and if I remember correctly, this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install boinc on Ubuntu Linux is:

**apt install boinc**

then edit **/etc/boinc-client/gui_rpc_auth.cfg** and enter a plain text password

then edit **/etc/boinc-client/remote_hosts.cfg** and enter config host

Then fire up your boinc client manager on Windows or Linux or whatever, point it at your boinc server, and start configuring it or monitoring running sessions. Make sure to take care of any firewall details if required (between your management client and boinc server).

And that's pretty much it.

Comment: Additionally, Ubuntu Software maybe be used and you can search for the Boinc package and then install it.